# What are the consequences of having many files in a directory in an ext4 filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, performance, ext4, json

My task is to store a list of JSONs on disk (without using any database) and I have these options:

- Store them in a single, large file.
- Store them in separate files, keyed by their IDs.

Personally I prefer the second option since it allows direct addressing any JSON by their ID without ever having to touch any other JSONs. However, there are almost 0.1 to 1 million JSON entries and I'm afraid of the possible negative consequences on the underlying filesystem (ext4 in my case):

- Will this go over filesystem limits about the number of files (either in a directory or in a whole filesystem)?
- Will this cause a slowdown while retrieving a specific ID?

  To be more specific, I believe the list of files under a directory are maintained by the directory's inode structure, but I'm not sure what data structures (list or map) it uses to keep the file list. Is there any performance gain in the lookup if I use a hierarchy of directories? For example, put `0123456789.json` into `root/01/0123456789.json` instead of `root/0123456789.json`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having 1 million files in a single directory would slow things down, but so would parsing an aggregate JSON with 1 million entries.  Your best bet is indeed to use hashed directories, but you probably want to go two levels deep rather than just one.  Namely, put `0123456789.json` in `root/0/01/0123456789.json`, and `987654321.json` in `root/9/98/987654321.json`.

Comment: Could you please be more elaborate on the first statement: *Having 1 million files in a single directory would slow things down*. So why would this happen? Does it mean directory inodes are storing filelist in a plain array?

Comment: If you want to understand the details consider reading about directory access on `ext4`.  A comment on SO isn't going to enlighten you.

Comment: Maybe [One billion files on Linux](https://lwn.net/Articles/400629/) can shed some light on this. While you are only storing 1 _million_ files, the more files in a directory (or per filesystem), the more work is to be done for the kernel and for userspace utilities too. You can test for yourself and try to store 1 million files in a directory and see how it goes.

Comment: @ckujau One million files in a filesystem != one million files _in the same directory_.