# How does a directory inode keep its file list?

Tags: filesystems, directory, inode

Does a directory inode use a plain array storing `( filename, inode )` pairs, or some kind of associative array `{ filename: inode }`to speed up file lookup, or any other optimizations on a plain array?

Take ext2/3/4 as example if you think the question is too broad or filesystem-specific.

This question is specifically focused on the internal representation of directory inodes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the consequences of having many files in a directory in an ext4 filesystem?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325288/what-are-the-consequences-of-having-many-files-in-a-directory-in-an-ext4-filesys)

Comment: @ckujau That one deals with a specific problem and contains issues that may be seen as off-topic for people who only want to know about the implementation of directory inodes.

Comment: for ext4 : https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inode_Table

Answer (score -1):

As we know,
everything is a file in Linux even the directories. Also every file has an inode.

That said, a directory's inode has a map of it's contents (files and subdirectories) into blocks (a block is part of a inode structure), it can be described with the following image:

[image]

Comment: First of all, a directory’s inode does no such thing.  A directory’s inode points to the directory’s data blocks, which contain the inode numbers and filenames of the files that are “in” the directory.  Secondly, the OP clearly knows that a directory associates inode numbers with filenames — the question says so.  (The OP probably already knows everything you said.)  But your image illustrates the association at only a conceptual level.  The question is: *how* do the ext2/3/4 filesystems do this?  Your illustration might have been relatively accurate twenty years ago; it’s not very useful now.